# <TargetName-Swift.h> file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6.3

I just updated my Xcode to 6.3 and my project which was working fine till xcode 6.2 started giving errors .

Error is `<TargetName-Swift.h> file not found` ,current path of bridging header is inside subfolder of project ,i.e one level inside .xcodeproj file .

Already tried

1. Deleting Bridging-Header file and recreating it .
2. Changing the path under Swift Compiler- Code generation under build settings
3. Also tried to change header search path ,but I think that was already correct .
4. Checked for circular reference , but i dont think that can be a problem because it was working fine before updating xcode .

Also somewhere I read it is generated at `"$(TARGET_TEMP_DIR)/../$(PROJECT_NAME).build/DerivedSources"`
 at this path , but didnot work for me .

****Edit *** 
Checked the log files generated it has error like "Opening import file for module 'Swift': Permission denied". Any idea ?? Of course I am super admin in the mac I am using .

Tried degrading Xcode again to 6.2 an everything worked well .

Any help would be great ..!!
Thanks .

Comment: Are you using swift 1.2? If not, then update swift and check

Comment: Apparently xcode6.3 comes default with swift1.2 ,so i guess that should not be a prob as m using xcode6.3.

Comment: Are you opening the `.xcproject` or the `.xcworkspace`?

Comment: sometimes loop import will also cause the problem. e.g. swift import objc class in bridge header file, objc class header file import swift.h

Answer (score 2):

This is due to build errors. `<TargetName-Swift.h>` is generated when there are no build errors.

Xcode 6.3 includes swift 1.2 which has some breaking changes compared with earlier swift version (distributed with xcode 6.2).

Comment: Hi ,

Thanks for response,but as I mentioned if I still run the same code in 6.2 it work fine ,so do u think there still can be compilation error ?

Comment: swift version in xcode 6.2 is different from swift version in xcode 6.3. So, same swift code which gets compiled in xcode 6.2 won't compile in xcode 6.3

Comment: Ohh ok,i will give it a try.

Answer (score -3):

1. Make sure you have **Objective-C Bridging Header** set to "TARGET_NAME/Your-Bridging-Header.h";" in the **Build Settings**
2. Open Terminal and run next commands:

   cd Project_Folder

   sudo chown -R `whoami` *

Comment: Bridging headers expose Obj-C to Swift. This is a Swift to Obj-C issue.